# html5 multi image upload show more than just image preview

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, forms

I'm currently playing around with html5 image upload. When I upload an image as part of a form there are also text inputs for the user to rename the file and add other info. This gets uploaded to MySQL via php. This is a sample form, the '$i' is used in php to add a number for each image. Currently I have to select how many images will be uploaded first, and that generates the below form with that many upload boxes.

```
Image '.$i.':<output id="display'.$i.'" ></output>

Choose Image:
<input name="file'.$i.'" type="file" id="file'.$i.'" class="upFile" accept="image/*" />

Ride:
<select name="ride_id_image'.$i.'">
    <option value="">Select Ride</option>   
    '.$options.'
    </select>

Description:
<input type="text" size="'.$textbox.'"  name="alt'.$i.'">


Credit:
<input type="text" size="'.$textbox.'"  name="credit'.$i.'"><input type="checkbox" name="flickr'.$i.'" value="FlickR: ">FlickR?
```

Now I know using javascript and html5 API you can generate an image preview for each image of a multi-upload. What I am wondering is, is it possible to have just one upload box, select lets say 5 files, then 5 image previews appear each with the text inputs for 'ride', 'description', 'credit' for each image to add the MySQL data?

I am completly new to Javascript so clueless as to if it can be done and how.
Thanks for any help

Extra info: Below is the API code I am trying to adapt, its from html5rocks and using one upload box to show multiple image previews.

```
<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```